# How to project differential forms on product spaces back to forms on the component spaces?

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms

Consider two differentiable manifolds $M^m,N^n$ and the associated set of differential forms for order $k \in \{0,\ldots,m\}$ and $q \in \{0,\ldots,n\}$, respectively $\Omega^k(M^m)$ and $\Omega^q(N^n)$.

Now consider the differentiable manifold $M^m \times N^n$ and the associated set of differential forms for order $l \in \{0,\ldots,m+n\}$, namely $\Omega^l(M^m \times N^n)$. Let's denote the canonical projections from the product space to the components by $\pi_M$ and $\pi_N$.

Well, there are some relations between the $\Omega$'s being considered above.

Notably, we have that $$\begin{matrix} \times :& \Omega^k(M^m) \times \Omega^q(N^n) & \rightarrow & \Omega^{k+l}(M^m \times N^n) \\  & (\omega,\eta) & \mapsto & \omega \times \eta := {\pi_M}^*\omega \wedge {\pi_N}^*\eta \end{matrix}$$  is an injective map.

Even though we can't hope to have this map $\times$ inverted (see these posts [(1)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261668/what-do-the-differential-k-forms-on-a-product-manifold-look-like) and [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824692/show-that-omegam-otimes-omegan-is-isomorphic-to-omegam-times-n)), as it fails to be surjective, my question is if we can put something in the opposite direction (analogous to taking the marginal of a measure on a product space):

Given $l \in \{0,\ldots,m+n\}$, let's fix a decomposition $l = k_0 + q_0$ with $k_0 \in \{0,\ldots,m\}$ and $q_0 \in \{0,\ldots,n\}$. Can we define some natural way a map $$\begin{matrix} \Pi_M: \Omega^l(M^m \times N^n) & \rightarrow & \Omega^{k_0}(M^m) \end{matrix}$$ so that, in particular, $\Pi_M (\omega \times \eta) = \omega$ for any $(\omega, \eta) \in \Omega^{k_0}(M^m) \times \Omega^{q_0}(N^n)$? If so, how?

Well, if so, we should have something similar in the $N$ component. And, just to be clear: we are not hoping that $\xi = \Pi_M(\xi) \times \Pi_N(\xi)$ for every $\xi \in \Omega^l(M^m \times N^n)$.

Also, we can't define something in this spirit but getting rid the decomposition choice $(k_0,q_0)$ above, right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $N$ is compact and oriented, then for each $k$ there is a linear map $\Pi_M: \Omega^{k+n}(M\times N) \to \Omega^k(M)$ called the ***pushforward*** or ***integration along the fiber***. Here's how that works. For any $\alpha\in \Omega^{k+n}(M\times N)$, define a form $\beta= \Pi_M\alpha\in \Omega^k(M)$ as follows: for arbitrary $x\in M$ and $v_1,\dots,v_k\in T_xM$,
$$
\beta_{x} (v_{1}, \dots, v_{k}) = \int _{\{x\}\times N} {\tilde v}_{1} \ \lrcorner\  {\tilde v}_{2} \ \lrcorner\  \dots \ \lrcorner\ {\tilde v}_{k} \ \lrcorner\  \alpha,
$$
where $\tilde v_j|_{(x,y)} = v_j \oplus 0 \in T_x M\oplus T_y N \cong T_{(x,y)}(M\times N)$.
In particular, if $\alpha = \omega\times\eta$, then
\begin{align*}
\beta_{x} (v_{1}, \dots, v_{k}) 
&= \int _{\{x\}\times N} \big( ​{\tilde v}_{1} \ \lrcorner\  {\tilde v}_{2} \ \lrcorner\  \dots \ \lrcorner\ {\tilde v}_{k} \ \lrcorner\  
\pi_M^*\omega\big)\pi_N^*\eta\\
&= \int _{\{x\}\times N} \big({v}_{1} \ \lrcorner\  {v}_{2} \ \lrcorner\  \dots \ \lrcorner\ {v}_{k} \ \lrcorner\  \omega_x\big)\pi_N^* \eta\\
&=\omega_x(v_1,\dots,v_k)\int _{N} \eta,
\end{align*}
so $\Pi_M(\omega\times\eta) = \Big(\int_N\eta\Big)\omega$.

You can use this operation to define a left inverse for $\pi_M^*\colon \Omega^k(M\times N)\to \Omega^k(M)$: just choose $\eta\in \Omega^n(N)$ such that $\int_N\eta=1$ (such a form exists because $N$ is compact and oriented), and define $\rho\colon \Omega^k(M\times N) \to \Omega^k(N)$ by $\rho\alpha = \Pi_M(\alpha\wedge \pi_N^*\eta)$. The calculation above shows that $\rho(\pi_M^*\omega) = \omega$.

An important feature of these maps is that they both commute with exterior differentiation: $\Pi_M(d\alpha) = d(\Pi_M\alpha)$ and $\rho(d\alpha) = d(\rho\alpha)$. The first equation can be proved by using a partition of unity to break up $\alpha$ into pieces that are compactly supported in product coordinate charts and doing the computation there; and the second one follows from the first because $d(\pi_N^*\eta)=\pi_N^*(d\eta)=0$. Thus both maps descend to maps on de Rham cohomology.

Comment: I get it! Many thanks for your answer! As we are integrating on $\{x\} \times N$, which is very natural, there consequences on the orders. Eg, say $m=n=10$. If $\omega$ and $\eta$ are 3-forms, we can do nothing. If $\omega$ and $\eta$ are 6-forms we can do something, but we won't ever recover any of them. If  $\omega$ is a 2-form and $\eta$ a 10-form, we can recover $\omega$ (modulo a constant factor) but not $\eta$. Only if both are 10-forms we'll be able to recover both. I am interpreting this correclty?
Also, in your first $=$, you want to use $\alpha$ instead of $\beta$ in the RHS, right?

Comment: Yes, you're interpreting it correctly. The only pushforward map (as far as I know) takes $(k+n)$-forms to $k$-forms, where $n=\dim  N$. And thanks for the correction -- fixed now.